# How to clear redux state for form errors on page change

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a redux store that holds errors. For my login and signup forms share the errors and if I switch forms, the errors remain. Now I know I could do something like

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  props.clearErrors();
}
...

const mapActionsToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
     ...,
     clearErrors: () => {
       dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR_ERRORS' });
     },
  }
};
```

However, I want to clear the errors on every page change.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the error on page change you should dispatch the action on page unmount, by `returning a function` with some logic in a `useEffect`:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  return () => props.clearErrors();
}
...

const mapActionsToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
     ...,
     clearErrors: () => {
       dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR_ERRORS' });
     },
  }
};
```